# Delay handler inside a loop in android

Tags: android, loops

I am trying to insert the handler to the loop but it makes it happen only once.

```
for(int i = 0;i<4;i++) {
    btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button to change between red and green with a delay of 2 seconds you can try something like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<4;i++) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
    }, 2000*2*i);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
    }, 2000*(2*i+1));
}
```

When using

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
            }, 2000)
```

you set the delay to a fixed value.
to make the button blink the delay has to be dynamic and changed every loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work for me, the loop is done only once

Comment: @גלעדאזולאי what is your goal?

Comment: @Giladazoolay the loop is done 4 times. you just do not see any effect because there is no delay between the loops. they happen immediately without waiting 2 seconds like the handler

Comment: the goal is that the button change color i times

Comment: @Giladazoolay use the first code snippet I edited it